# Custom TextField does not comply to constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, constraints

I've been having this issue with [HoshiTextField](https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects/blob/master/TextFieldEffects/TextFieldEffects/HoshiTextField.swift) for quite some time now, I also opened an issue on git but didn't get an answer...

This is how it should look like and how it looks like if the user is selecting the `textField`:

[image]

The problem occurs when setting the `textField` to `becomeFirstResponder` inside `viewDidLoad` or when `popping` a `ViewController` while the `textField` inside the first `VC` was selected. Apparently that messes up the `frames` or `constraints` of the `textField` but I have absolutely no idea how to fix this.

[image]

As you can see the "Email-Adesse"-text is moving to the upper left and when `pushing` and `poping` back to the `ViewController` it moves even further outside the `constraints`. When checking the `View Hirarchy` with the debugger the "Email-Adresse"-Text looks perfectly in place even though it isn't. Setting up the constraints inside `viewDidAppear` didn't change anything.

I constrain the `textFields` like every other element:

```
let emailTextField: HoshiTextField = {
    let v = HoshiTextField()
    v.borderActiveColor = .white
    v.borderInactiveColor = .white
    v.textColor = .white
    v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 17)
    v.placeholder = "Email-Adresse"
    v.placeholderColor = .white
    v.placeholderFontScale = 0.8
    v.minimumFontSize = 13
    v.borderStyle = .line
    v.autocapitalizationType = .none
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
emailTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    emailTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    emailTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
```

If anyone can help me out here I would be so grateful! I hope the problem is clear, you can also look at my project to see the problem yourself:

[Git repo to my project](https://github.com/DieGlueckswurst/Wishlist)

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to say that I can't seem to recreate the problem. I downloaded your project, and I click on "Mit Email Fortfahren" but the Hoshi Text Field works normally on selection. Is there something else I should be doing? I'm running XCode 11.3 though, dont know if you are using a later one.

Comment: like I said, when selecting the textfield everything works perfectly fine. Try tapping on "weiter" and then going back with the "back-button" in the upper-left corner. That will reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full test controller with 2 alternates of possible solution

Demo: Alternate 1 - often appears already expanded

[image: demo]

Demo: Alternate 2 - always there is a delay, expanding is visible

[image: demo2]

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var theLabel: UILabel!
    private weak var emailTextField: HoshiTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        emailTextField = {
            let v = HoshiTextField()
            v.borderActiveColor = .white
            v.borderInactiveColor = .white
            v.textColor = .white
            v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 17)
            v.placeholder = "Email-Adresse"
            v.placeholderColor = .white
            v.placeholderFontScale = 0.8
            v.minimumFontSize = 13
            v.borderStyle = .line
            v.autocapitalizationType = .none
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return v
        }()
        self.view.addSubview(emailTextField)
        emailTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            emailTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
            emailTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
            emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

//        DispatchQueue.main.async {
//            self.emailTextField.becomeFirstResponder()    // Alternate 1
//        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        emailTextField.becomeFirstResponder()          // Alternate 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I also added it to the `Subview`.. Are you sure it is working? Can you call `becomeFirstResponder()` inside `viewDidLoad` and it is actually being displayed the correct way?

Comment: @Chris, got it - see fix in updated answer. As alternate you can keep reference to `emailTextField` as member and call `becomeFirstResponder` directly in overridden `viewDidAppear`

Comment: yes, exactly in `viewDidAppear` (not `will..`), but visual effect is a bit different than in variant provided in answer, so you'd better try both, which one is more expected in your workflow.

Comment: could you send me a screenshot of how it looks when the VC is first presented? So I can see if it is actually the desired look

Comment: bruh. Like you said above. I had it inside `willAppear`. Calling inside `viewDidAppear` works perfectly fine. Been struggling with this issue for a month now:D thanks man !! Get that bounty :D

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood your question at first.

I feel like the issue is that at some point as the `HoshiTextField` is selected and leaves the screen, it becomes deselected, but it does not update it's layout. So then when you come back the animations still stay relatively the same, but from a different angle.

I'm not sure how to solve that problem precisely, but I was able to get the screen to look normal after adding the following to your `EmailVC`

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

I hope that that's fine. It's not really solving the issue, but it does get the UI of your app looking proper in this scenario.

Comment: I tried using `resignFirstResponder` on the textField instead but that does not work for some reason.

Comment: thanks for your help! That is actually working but like you already said, unfortunately not really solving the whole problem :/